# Unresolved external symbol with google test framework

Tags: unit-testing, linker, googletest

I try to implement google test framework for verifing dll library into my existed solution by visual studio community 2019. Basically, I have 3 files:
Source code is built in single dll project.

```
FooCmdMgr.cpp
FooCmdMgr.h
```

Unit test code using the latest google test framework in other project in a same solution with source code.

```
FooCmdMgr_Test.cpp
```

**FooCmdMgr.h**

```
class FooCmdMgr
{   
public:
    FooCmdMgr(const FooCmdMgr&) = delete;
    FooCmdMgr& operator=(const FooCmdMgr& ) = delete;

    bool func_1() {
        return true;
    }

private:
    FooCmdMgr();
    ~FooCmdMgr();

    static FooCmdMgr&       Instance                ( );
    friend  FooCmdMgr&      GetFooCmdMgr            ( );
};

inline FooCmdMgr&   GetFooCmdMgr()
{
    return FooCmdMgr::Instance();
}
```

**FooCmdMgr_Test.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../FooCmdMgr.h"

 
    TEST_F(CJobChangeTestFixture, UnitTest2) {

        FooCmdMgr& FooCmdMgr = ICmdEx::FooCmdMgr();
        //bool bRet = FooCmdMgr.func_1();
        //EXPECT_EQ(bRet, true);
    }
```

Solution was compliled successful but linker was not OK.
It shown error LNK2019 something likes this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "private: static class ICmdEx::FooCmdMgr & __cdecl ICmdEx::FooCmdMgr::Instance(void)" (?Instance@FooCmdMgr@ICmdEx@@CAAEAV12@XZ) referenced in function "class ICmdEx::FooCmdMgr & __cdecl ICmdEx::GetIKYCmdMgr(void)" (?GetIKYCmdMgr@ICmdEx@@YAAEAVFooCmdMgr@1@XZ)   IEditorDll_GTest    E:\work\project\UnitTest\FooCmdMgr_Test.obj
```

Project structure

```
E:\work\project\FooCmdMgr.vcxproj
E:\work\project\FooCmdMgr.cpp
E:\work\project\FooCmdMgr.h
E:\work\project\FooCmdMgr.dll
E:\work\project\FooCmdMgr.lib
```

Google test project

```
E:\work\project\UnitTest\FooCmdMgr_Test.vcxproj
E:\work\project\UnitTest\FooCmdMgr_Test.cpp
```

I also change the configuration of linker in gtest project
General/Additional Library Directories

```
$(ProjectDir)../
```

Input/Additional Dependencies/

```
FooCmdMgr.lib
```

I am struggling to figure out what happened with linker? Please give me advise.

Comment: Have you added the dependency of `FooCmdMgr` to your test target? Sth like `target_link_libraries(test_target_name FooCmdMgr)` in CMakeLitsts.txt.

Comment: I did'nt use CMake in my project. FooCmdMgr is MFC Dynamic-Link library

Comment: OK, so in Visual Studio you need to reference the lib under test, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-testing-in-visual-studio/#Setup

Comment: @Quarra: Thank you for your answer, your mentioned article related to Microsoft Native C++ Unit Test Framework. However, I have to apply Google Test Framework for my project. More, I also added the relevant lib in "reference". It did not work well. Furthermore, if I create the simpler class in FooCmdMgr.h and comment out the "class FooCmdMgr". It worked OK.

Answer (score 1):

your Foo class should be like this

```
    #pragma once
#ifdef PROJECT1_EXPORTS
#define PROJECT1_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PROJECT1_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class PROJECT1_API Foo
{
};
```

PROJECT1_EXPORTS is defined in your main source PREPROCESSOR project.
and it will NOT be define in your Test project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding the output .obj/.lib files to the dependencies of the test project as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/unit-testing-existing-cpp-applications-with-test-explorer?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#objectRef

I have Visual Studio 2022 with Google Test, and for me, it was enough to perform only steps 2 to 4 from the instruction. I.e.:

1. In Solution Explorer, on the shortcut menu of the test project, choose Properties. The project properties window opens.
2. Choose **Configuration Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies**.

   Choose Edit, and add the names of the **.obj** or **.lib** files. Do not use the full path names.
   [image: linker-input]
3. Choose **Configuration Properties, Linker, General, Additional Library Directories**.

   Choose **Edit**, and add the directory path of the **.obj** or **.lib** files. The path is typically within the build folder of the project under test.

I use NVIDIA CUDA, so needed to add its .lib file and path too.